# Query in Eloquent works when it shouldn't - in MySQL, it fails as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

If you have an integer field setup in MySQL, no nulls allowed, default null, and you write a query that omits this field, in Laravel the query still executes, and the default value of null isn't used, but instead written as '0'.

If I take the exact, generated query by Eloquent/query builder, and run it in MySQL, it fails, rightly stating that the field in question must have a default value.

Why is there this discrepancy? What the hell is eloquent/query builder/pdo doing?!

create table syntax below:

```
CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`account_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`season_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `chapters_account_id_index` (`account_id`),
KEY `chapters_season_id_index` (`season_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6060 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Doing an insert and omitting account_id in MySQL, fails - as it should. Doing the same in Eloquent/Laravel, does not, despite the generated query being correct.

Comment: Can you provide examples of the query along with a brief schema out, and the Laravel SQL? it's possible that if you've defined an attribute in the model for the table in Laravel, it is adding the field to the SQL query when saving.

Comment: Yeah, it's not doing that. It's omitting the field (at least that's what it says it's doing) and still inserting successfully. Yet when I copy the query that was supposedly executed directly into MySQL, it fails as expected.

Comment: Have updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out what was going on. Laravel by default sets strict rules to false in config/database.php. This turns off all sorts of options regarding strict mode, such as full group bys, strict trans table.etc.

What we did is set STRICT_ALL_TABLES on our my.cnf and then enforced laravel to strict = true. This solves it.